# Ruby evaluation order

Tags: ruby

```
print sentence.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).all? do |word|
    @words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym
end
```

I've printed the individual values of `@words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym` and they are not all true, yet it prints `true`. I think this might be because its evaluated like so:

```
(print sentence.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).all?) do |word|
    @words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym
end
```

but I want it to evaluate like

```
print (sentence.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).all? do |word|
    @words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym
end)
```

However, adding the parentheses results in

```
syntax error, unexpected keyword_do_block, expecting ')'
```

**How do I change the order in which the piece of code is evaluated?**

**Edit:**

I would like to return true instead of print unless the above is true, like:

```
    @sentences.reject do |sentence|
        !(sentence.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).all? { |word| @words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym })
    end
```

But it rejects everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating pain for yourself in a couple of ways:

1. The argument to print is ambiguous. You should use `print(...)` with no spaces.
2. Do/end binds less tightly than a `{...}` block. Again, your example is somewhat ambiguous for the parser.

Try the less ambiguous syntax, and see if that clears things up before looking at alternative constructions.

Answer (score 3):

This variant works for me:

```
print (sentence.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).all?{|word| words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym })
```

Second variant:

```
print begin
  (sentence.scan(/\[(\w+)\]/).all? do |word|
    words.keys.include? word[0].to_sym
  end)    
end
```

Comment: Ahh yeah, thanks. Why does do ... end not work in parentheses?

Comment: Maybe because of parser, it can't be smart in every cases, see the second variant.